# Nokogiri Sax Parser to return an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri, sax

I am using Nokogiri with Sax to parse an xml file:

```
@active_ids = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(IdParser.new).parse(open("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/redacted/client_xml.xml"))
```

Inside the parser, I am building an array of ids and would like to return them once the parser is done:

```
def initialize
  @array_of_ids = []
end
def start_element(name, attrs = [])
  @array_of_ids << attrs[0][1].to_s if name == "job"
end      
def end_document
  return @array_of_ids
end
```

Unfortunately, the returning array is nil (I tried providing a simple string, same result). Is there a problem in providing the return value? How can I communicate with my parser?

Comment: Please post your code of array conversion... and xml sample...

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum program and the minimum data that demonstrates the problem _in the question itself_. We also need to know your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Need to structure the call differently. If I want an array of ids, then I can access this via the document attribute (have to decode and encode to json to handle it nicely, as I don't understand the format provided by the parser):

```
  f = open("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xml.xml")
  id_parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(IdParser.new)
  id_parser.parse(f)
  @active_ids = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(id_parser.to_json)["document"]["array_of_ids"]
```